# I can't get the Controller in the laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a problem accessing a Controller that I created via terminal:

```
php artisan make:controller Admin\TestController
```

This is the TestController class I created

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function teste()
    {
        return 'Teste Controller';
    }
}
```

Here is the routes file, where I will try to call the `teste` method. By default, the correct thing would be to call the TestController in the Admin folder.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/test', 'Admin\TestController@teste');
```

In the Web.php file when I update the page, the message appears:

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException Target class
[Admin\TestController] does not exist.
```

It only works when I put the full directory:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/test', 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\TestController@teste');
```

But I did not want to put the complete directory for reasons of a leaner code and easy to understand.

How can I call the TestController without placing the complete directory?

I'm using the Laravel Framework: `8.9.0`

I'm using php: `7.2.19 (cli)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [upgrade](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#) documentation of **Laravel 8**,  you can use PHP callable syntax like this way :

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\TestController;

Route::get('/test', [TestController::class, 'teste']);
```

Answer (score 1):

this is because of the latest version of Laravel that you are using.
Read the documentation for the latest Laravel version [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#basic-routing)!

Answer (score 0):

Yupp, as mentioned above, for the new Laravel Version 8.x, in the routes.php, you have to mention the controller class as in array format, for example

```
<?php
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller_Name;

Route::get('/', [Controller_Name::class,'Function_Name']); ?>
```

*Also don't forget to import that controller class.*

Here's [link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#basic-routing) for Laravel 8.x referring the routing.

Hope it helps. Thank You